# Suspension on invoking method jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

**Hello everyone!**
I have a application, which configured with spring 3 and hibernate 3. In application all requests to database with a JDBCTemplate and HibernateTemplate. In my case i have a method, which registers an array parameter:

```
protected void registerArrayParameter(PreparedStatement st, int num, Long[] mas) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    OracleConnection ocon = (OracleConnection) ((DelegatingConnection) conn).getInnermostDelegate();
    ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CCSYS.NUMBER_TABLE", ocon);
    java.sql.Array sqlArray = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, ocon, mas);
    st.setArray(num, sqlArray);
}
```

Often application suspend (freezing) on jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().
Could somebody know what it can be? 
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Don't do `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()` as this requests an connection outside of springs transaction management. Which will remain open until it times out. At some point your connection pool gets depleted which results in suspension/freezing of your application.

Comment: are you using Java 1.6.0_29?

Comment: isah, i am using jdk1.6.0_24

Comment: M. Deinum, how can i realize this method another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
In my case i have a class extends BasicDataSourse:

```
public class SomeSource extends BasicDataSource implements Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 4467486478647684235L;
    public static SomeSource dataSource;

    public SomeSource(){
        super();
        /* implementation*/
        ....
        dataSource = this;
    }
}
```

I have modified method, which registers an array parameter:

```
protected void registerArrayParameter(PreparedStatement st, int num, Long[] mas) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    OracleConnection ocon = (OracleConnection) ((DelegatingConnection) conn).getInnermostDelegate();
    ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CCSYS.NUMBER_TABLE", ocon);
    java.sql.Array sqlArray = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, ocon, mas);
    st.setArray(num, sqlArray);

    /*added*/
    conn.close();
    ocon.close();
    SomeSource.dataSource.close();
}
```

After that the application steel working without suspend/freezing...